# How to send new passwords securely across to the server

Tags: wcf, web-services, security, ssl

My client-side code calls the REST WCF service for changing passwords. I defined changePassword with "UriTemplate" set to "?user={userName}&oldPwd={oldHashPwd}&newPwd={newEncryptPwd}"

My question is: how to encrypt the new password on the client side so that we can successfully decrypt it on the server side ? Please be specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yinfang. You don't need to be worry to encrypt your password from client side that would only be decrypted on the server side. Now a days, there are so many channels through which you can protect you personal data like your passwords. One way is to check that whether yo use "HTTPS"  for your browsing because it will provide you secure channel to send you information from one place to another.

On the other hand you can get VPN connection. Through which all of your information gets encrypted and provided secure channel to pass your personal sensitive data from client side to server. There are so many providers of VPN connection are available in the market like PureVPN, Hidemyass,switchvpn etc etc. If you want all of your information encrypted ans secure you can use these useful information.

Answer (score 5):

Use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure). If the whole communication is encrypted, you won't even need to encrypt/decrypt the password individually.

Comment: this. HTTPS is what you should be doing for transport level security.

Comment: @YinfangZhuang, you should ask that as a separate question on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 1):

Beyond HTTPS, you could use a secure, salted password hash on the client side.  That would mean even interception of the URL would be safe - having the hash would allow efficient "proof of ownership", but not discovery of the password.

Comment: My question is if you hash the original password how can you recover it from the hash value ? Eventually I need the new password to update my backend database.

Comment: You can directly store the hashed value in your database, which will allow you to verify the user submitted the correct password at a later date.  Your question suggests that you are storing plain text passwords, which is a really, really bad idea.  Don't do that.  Do your users a favour and only ever store hashed passwords.  Don't be the next big news item when you get hacked.

Comment: 'If you hash the original password how can you recover it from the hash value?' You can't. That's good. You just compare the hash values. You don't want to be able to recover the original passwords, for all sorts of serious legal reasons.

Comment: Do NOT hash the password on the client side and just send to the server to compare. This is a horrible practice. If your server's username/password table were to be compromised, an attacker would know exactly what to send to your server to log in as any user (user A has hash X, so just send A/X as UN/PW and the server will let you in). You want to send the actual password to the server, so it can hash it there and then compare the result to the stored value (user A has hash X, but I cannot figure out what value hashes to X so I don't know what to send as the PW).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help. I use to encrypt data using `Rijndael`
Sample code here:
[Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx)

You can create logic on backend side and be used by the client side for encrypting and decrypting data.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to go with either "https" or "VPN/Proxy". Going through 'https' won't hazel much while encrypting anything on the web. I will give you smooth path to surf the web and do whatever you want. But the point is that if you are looking to get something more than just encryption then you should try VPN/Proxy. If you can google around then you will find that proxy is not that much safer. However, going through VPN is completely opposite to proxy. VPN is one of the best and most reliable feature that a user can have for their web. VPN absolutely anonymize one's identity and allow the local ISP to surf (encrypt/decrypt) user data with out any threats from hackers.